# How to create random orthonormal matrix in python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, orthogonal

Is there a method that I can call to create a random orthonormal matrix in python? Possibly using numpy? Or is there a way to create a orthonormal matrix using multiple numpy methods? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the `rvs` method pulled from the https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/5622/files, with minimal change - just enough to run as a stand alone numpy function.

```
import numpy as np    

def rvs(dim=3):
     random_state = np.random
     H = np.eye(dim)
     D = np.ones((dim,))
     for n in range(1, dim):
         x = random_state.normal(size=(dim-n+1,))
         D[n-1] = np.sign(x[0])
         x[0] -= D[n-1]*np.sqrt((x*x).sum())
         # Householder transformation
         Hx = (np.eye(dim-n+1) - 2.*np.outer(x, x)/(x*x).sum())
         mat = np.eye(dim)
         mat[n-1:, n-1:] = Hx
         H = np.dot(H, mat)
         # Fix the last sign such that the determinant is 1
     D[-1] = (-1)**(1-(dim % 2))*D.prod()
     # Equivalent to np.dot(np.diag(D), H) but faster, apparently
     H = (D*H.T).T
     return H
```

It matches Warren's test, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38426572/901925

Comment: This answer is good, but is now outdated; The newer answer referencing scipy.stats.ortho_group is now more appropriate.

Answer (score 49):

Version 0.18 of scipy has [`scipy.stats.ortho_group`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ortho_group.html) and [`scipy.stats.special_ortho_group`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.special_ortho_group.html#scipy.stats.special_ortho_group).  The pull request where it was added is https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/5622

For example,

```
In [24]: from scipy.stats import ortho_group  # Requires version 0.18 of scipy

In [25]: m = ortho_group.rvs(dim=3)

In [26]: m
Out[26]: 
array([[-0.23939017,  0.58743526, -0.77305379],
       [ 0.81921268, -0.30515101, -0.48556508],
       [-0.52113619, -0.74953498, -0.40818426]])

In [27]: np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

In [28]: m.dot(m.T)
Out[28]: 
array([[ 1.,  0., -0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [-0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Thank you  for your response. I have noticed that the answers given are all for square matrices. Can I still use this method to obtain a d x k matrix, where k < d?

Comment: Construct a d x d matrix and then drop extra columns

Answer (score 28):

You can obtain a random `n x n` orthogonal matrix `Q`, (uniformly distributed over the manifold of `n x n` orthogonal matrices) by performing a `QR` factorization of an `n x n` matrix with elements i.i.d. Gaussian random variables of mean `0` and variance `1`. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import qr

n = 3
H = np.random.randn(n, n)
Q, R = qr(H)

print (Q.dot(Q.T))
```

> ```
> [[  1.00000000e+00  -2.77555756e-17   2.49800181e-16]
>  [ -2.77555756e-17   1.00000000e+00  -1.38777878e-17]
>  [  2.49800181e-16  -1.38777878e-17   1.00000000e+00]]
> ```

EDIT: (Revisiting this answer after the comment by @g g.) The claim above on the QR decomposition of a Gaussian matrix providing a uniformly distributed (over the, so called, Stiefel manifold) orthogonal matrix is suggested by Theorems 2.3.18-19 of [this reference](https://books.google.gr/books?id=PQOYnT7P1loC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA68#v=onepage&q&f=false). Note that the statement of the result suggests a "QR-like" decomposition, however, *with the triangular matrix `R` having positive elements*.

Apparently, the `qr` function of scipy (numpy) function *does not guarantee positive diagonal elements for `R`* and the corresponding `Q` is actually *not* uniformly distributed. This has been observed in [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjZ_IrPvPLhAhXF6aQKHe4OB9UQFjAEegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.eecs.umich.edu%2F~rajnrao%2FActa05rmt.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3uKhMwG-eUahHY2_iA9V3b) monograph, Sec. 4.6 (the discussion refers to MATLAB, but I guess both MATLAB and scipy use the same LAPACK routines). It is suggested there that the matrix `Q` provided by `qr` is modified by post multiplying it  with a random unitary diagonal matrix.

Below I reproduce the experiment in the above reference, plotting the empirical distribution (histogram) of phases of eigenvalues of the "direct" `Q` matrix provided by `qr`, as well as the "modified" version, where it is seen that the modified version does indeed have a uniform eigenvalue phase, as would be expected from a uniformly distributed orthogonal matrix.

```
from scipy.linalg import qr, eigvals
from seaborn import distplot

n = 50
repeats = 10000

angles = []
angles_modified = []
for rp in range(repeats):
    H = np.random.randn(n, n)
    Q, R = qr(H)
    angles.append(np.angle(eigvals(Q)))
    Q_modified = Q @ np.diag(np.exp(1j * np.pi * 2 * np.random.rand(n)))
    angles_modified.append(np.angle(eigvals(Q_modified))) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize = (10,3))
distplot(np.asarray(angles).flatten(),kde = False, hist_kws=dict(edgecolor="k", linewidth=2), ax= ax[0])
ax[0].set(xlabel='phase', title='direct')
distplot(np.asarray(angles_modified).flatten(),kde = False, hist_kws=dict(edgecolor="k", linewidth=2), ax= ax[1])
ax[1].set(xlabel='phase', title='modified');
```

[image]

Comment: How do you know the resulting matrices are uniformly distributed over the manifold? And according to what measure on the manifold?

Comment: @gg Thanks for the comment! Actually, the "direct" application of `qr` does not provide a uniformly distributed orthogonal matrix. Please see the edited answer for a workaround.

Comment: Great answer! The references are pertinent and much appreciated!

Comment: The random angles are not needed, just use the signs from the diagonals of R: `Q_modified = Q @ np.diag(np.sign(np.diag(R))`

Answer (score 8):

An easy way to create any shape (`n x m`) orthogonal matrix:

```
import numpy as np

n, m = 3, 5

H = np.random.rand(n, m)
u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(H, full_matrices=False)
mat = u @ vh

print(mat @ mat.T) # -> eye(n)
```

Note that if `n > m`, it would obtain `mat.T @ mat = eye(m)`.

Comment: I think that you should change `rand` into `randn` to obtain a uniform distribution of the matrices. Otherwise the best answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

```
from scipy.stats import special_ortho_group
num_dim=3
x = special_ortho_group.rvs(num_dim)
```

[Documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.special_ortho_group.html#scipy.stats.special_ortho_group)

Answer (score 4):

if you want a none Square Matrix with orthonormal column vectors you could create a square one with any of the mentioned method and drop some columns.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy also has qr factorization. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.qr.html

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(3, 3)
q, r = np.linalg.qr(a)

q @ q.T
# array([[ 1.00000000e+00,  8.83206468e-17,  2.69154044e-16],
#        [ 8.83206468e-17,  1.00000000e+00, -1.30466244e-16],
#        [ 2.69154044e-16, -1.30466244e-16,  1.00000000e+00]])
```