# Tensorflow: How to generate a random orthogonal matrix in data preprocessing pipeline using tensorflow.contrib.data module?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to generate a random orthogonal matrix to randomly rotate my 3D point cloud data in the data preprocessing state. (I have found a numpy implementation [How to create random orthonormal matrix in python numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426349/how-to-create-random-orthonormal-matrix-in-python-numpy))

As is suggested, I'm using TensorFlow's new Dataset API.

1.I have tried directly transferring the Numpy code into Tf code, I met the problem that TensorFlow does not allow slicing assignment (TF even does not allow assign for ordinary tensors).

2.I'm trying

```
def _rotate_point_cloud_ortho(self, single_data):
    rotation_matrix = tf.Variable(tf.constant(rvs(), shape=[3,3]), name='rotation_matrix', trainable=False)
    self.initializer = rotation_matrix.initialized_value()
    rotation_matrix.assign(rvs())
    return tf.matmul(single_data, rotation_matrix)
```

And got

```
ValueError: Fetch argument <tf.Tensor 'cond/Merge:0' shape=(3, 3) dtype=float32> cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Tensor Tensor("cond/Merge:0", shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.)
```

3.I'm thinking of using placeholder for the random orthogonal matrix, but the dataset API uses map, so it's hard to pass a matrix in.

I cannot realize where this error come from.

Except hard-coding the Numpy implementation into a function generating 9 tf variables, and then stacking these variables into a 3*3 matrix, what else can I try?

The code for my current API:
    class PointCloudDataGenerator(object):

```
    def __init__(self, tfrecord_path, mode, batch_size,
                  buffer_size=9824):
        # create dataset
        self.initializer = None
        data = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecord_path)

        # distinguish between train/infer. when calling the parsing functions
        if mode == 'training':
            data = data.map(self._parse_function_train, num_threads=4, output_buffer_size=100*batch_size)

        elif mode == 'inference':
            data = data.map(self._parse_function_inference, num_threads=4, output_buffer_size=100*batch_size)
        else:
          raise ValueError("Invalid mode '%s'." % (mode))

        # number of samples in the dataset
        self.data_size = 9840 if mode == 'training' else 2468

        # shuffle the first `buffer_size` elements of the dataset
        if mode == 'training':
            data = data.shuffle(buffer_size=buffer_size)

        # create a new dataset with batches of images
        data = data.batch(batch_size)
        self.data = data
```