# numerical diagonalization of a unitary matrix

Tags: matrix, lapack, eigenvector

To numerically diagonalize a *unitary matrix* I use the LAPACK routine [zgeev](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/db/d55/group__complex16_g_eeigen_ga0eb4e3d75621a1ce1685064db1ac58f0.html).

The problem is: In case of degeneracies the degenerate subspace is not orthonormalized, since the routine is for general matrices.

However, since in my case the matrices are unitary, the *basis can be always orthonormalized*. Is there a better solution than applying QR-algorithm afterwards to the degenerate subspace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **[`Schur decomposition`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node50.html)!**

If a square matrix `A` is complex, then its Schur factorization is **`A=ZTZ*`**, where `Z` is unitary and `T` is upper triangular.
If `A` happens to be unitary, `T` must also be unitary. Since `T` is both unitary and triangular, it is diagonal [(proof here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115304/unitary-and-upper-triangular-matrix).[or there)](http://mathhelpforum.com/advanced-algebra/96975-solved-prove-matrix-both-unitary-upper-triangular-must-diagon.html)
Let's consider the vectors `Z.e_i`, where e_i are the vectors of the canonical basis. These vectors obviously form an orthonormal basis. Moreover, these vectors are eigenvectors of the matrix `A`.
**Hence, the columns of the unitary matrix Z are eigenvectors of the unitary matrix `A` and form an orthonormal basis.**

As a consequence, computing a Schur decomposition of a unitary matrix is equivalent to finding one of its orthogonal basis of eigenvectors.

[`ZGEESX` computes the eigenvalues, the Schur form, and, optionally, the matrix of Schur vectors for GE matrices](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/zgeesx.f.html)

The resulting `T` can also be tested to check that `A` is unitary.

Here is a piece of python code testing it, though scipy's `scipy.linalg.schur`  makes use of Lapack's zgees for Schur decomposition. I used hpaulj's code to generate random unitary matrix as shown in [How to create random orthonormal matrix in python numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426349/how-to-create-random-orthonormal-matrix-in-python-numpy)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg

#from hpaulj, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426349/how-to-create-random-orthonormal-matrix-in-python-numpy
def rvs(dim=3):
     random_state = np.random
     H = np.eye(dim)
     D = np.ones((dim,))
     for n in range(1, dim):
         x = random_state.normal(size=(dim-n+1,))
         D[n-1] = np.sign(x[0])
         x[0] -= D[n-1]*np.sqrt((x*x).sum())
         # Householder transformation
         Hx = (np.eye(dim-n+1) - 2.*np.outer(x, x)/(x*x).sum())
         mat = np.eye(dim)
         mat[n-1:, n-1:] = Hx
         H = np.dot(H, mat)
         # Fix the last sign such that the determinant is 1
     D[-1] = (-1)**(1-(dim % 2))*D.prod()
     # Equivalent to np.dot(np.diag(D), H) but faster, apparently
     H = (D*H.T).T
     return H

n=42
A= rvs(n)
A = A.astype(complex)
T,Z=scipy.linalg.schur(A,output='complex',lwork=None,overwrite_a=False,sort=None,check_finite=True)

#print T
normT=np.linalg.norm(T,ord=None) #2-norm
eigenvalues=[]
for i in range(n):
    eigenvalues.append(T[i,i])
    T[i,i]=0.
normTu=np.linalg.norm(T,ord=None)
print 'must be very low if A is unitary: ',normTu/normT

#print Z
for i in range(n):
    v=Z[:,i]
    w=A.dot(v)-eigenvalues[i]*v
    print i,'must be very low if column i of Z is eigenvector of A: ',np.linalg.norm(w,ord=None)/np.linalg.norm(v,ord=None)
```