# Create random matrix with orthonormal columns?

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

In Julia, is there any function or way to generate a random matrix with **orthonormal columns** of arbitrary dimensions (not necessarily square, could be rectangular/tall matrix)?

Comment: what do you mean by a random matrix? What distribution do you want?

Comment: I guess James means this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426349/how-to-create-random-orthonormal-matrix-in-python-numpy   seems one way is to call SciPy via PyCall.jl

Comment: You can read https://nhigham.com/2020/04/22/what-is-a-random-orthogonal-matrix/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the columns of `Q` in a [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) are orthonormal, I think you could just perform a QR decomposition on a random matrix.

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> qr(rand(5)).Q
5×5 LinearAlgebra.QRCompactWYQ{Float64, Matrix{Float64}, Matrix{Float64}}:
 -0.418858  -0.339672   -0.113064   -0.664132   -0.505298
 -0.339672   0.918683   -0.0270673  -0.158992   -0.120967
 -0.113064  -0.0270673   0.99099    -0.0529223  -0.0402654
 -0.664132  -0.158992   -0.0529223   0.689136   -0.236517
 -0.505298  -0.120967   -0.0402654  -0.236517    0.820048
```

If you don't need all 5 columns, you can just take the first k that you need.